# Spring Boot hibernate error ComandAcceptanceException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to teach myself a little of spring framework so I have a little springboot application with web extension, jpa and apache derby. When i tried to run this little example i encountered a strange error. From what i understand it says that "drop table topic" is an sql syntax error? I have no idea what to do with it. Below is the code for the class that should be converted to an sql table and the error itself. Please help!

```
package com.example.demo.topic;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic(){}

    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table topic" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:246) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:157) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) [hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) [spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$175/1436633036.getObject(Unknown Source) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) [spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) [spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) [spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.StatementUtil.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.justGetDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DropTableNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist

Check the configuration for Database in the spring properties

1. Make sure there is a schema **SA** .
2. Make sure the database name is Syntax correctly .

If it exists and everything is correct, change the property **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** from **create-drop** to **update**

Comment: Thank you very much I just added this line spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update and error went away. I just do not now what happended:D I don't even know what schema SA is.

Comment: @Bogdan Often this is because the table that would have been deleted is **linked** to another table and that table **must be deleted first**. The property **update** allows adding the modification without erasing, that is, modifying the old data as it is, while the property **create-drop** deletes all data and tables and creates them again, so Perhaps the problem is in the order in which the tables are deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From what i understand my example should have only one table topic and that is it at least I did not define any other entity than Topic.

Comment: @Bogdan also the schema not exists error if your application tries to access the current schema before any objects have been created in it. Possibilities are you try to perform a DROP TABLE before creating it , The same problem is discussed here  [An error that usually occurs in Derby databases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7706)

Answer (score 0):

When you get any exception/error in spring boot always check at the bottom **caused by**,  that would give you the clear picture of what's wrong with your code/configuration.

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
```